# How can I customize the style in cdk draggable mode?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have programmed a small list of characters. These contain mat-checkboxes and you can move them around using Cdk Drag Drop. All good so far! Now would also like to customize the style draggable as well. I read that you can do it with the class .cdk-drag-preview. I also use this class for box-shadow. I tried to access mat-checkboxes via .cdk-drag-preview and style them. Unfortunately this did not work. Do you know how to do this?

My WORK in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-drop-vsge6t?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.css

My Code:

```
// HTML

<form [formGroup]="reportCompositionForm">
  <div class="drag-container">
    <div cdkDropListGroup>
      <div
        cdkDropList
        [cdkDropListData]="displayCharactersArray"
        class="item-list"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      >
        <div
          class="item-box"
          *ngFor="let element of displayCharactersArray; let i = index"
          cdkDrag
        >
          <mat-checkbox (change)="onChange($event)" [value]="element">
            <span (click)="deactivateCheckBoxClickEvent($event)">
              {{ element.viewValue }}
            </span>
          </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
// CSS
.drag-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 400px;
}

.item-list {
  display: block;
}

.item-box {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #9594947a;
  border: 1px solid #9594947a;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: move;
}

.cdk-drag-preview {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.item-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .item-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

:host ::ng-deep .item-box mat-checkbox label.mat-checkbox-layout {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

:host
  ::ng-deep
  .item-box
  mat-checkbox
  label.mat-checkbox-layout
  span.mat-checkbox-label
  span {
  cursor: move;
}

:host
  ::ng-deep
  .item-box
  mat-checkbox
  label.mat-checkbox-layout
  span.mat-checkbox-inner-container
  .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: #e1dfdf;
}

:host
  ::ng-deep
  .item-box
  mat-checkbox
  label.mat-checkbox-layout
  span.mat-checkbox-inner-container
  .mat-checkbox-ripple
  .mat-ripple-element {
  background-color: transparent;
}

:host
  ::ng-deep
  .item-box
  .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent
  .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Which version of Angular Material/CDK are you using? Is it the version `7.0.0` as used in Stackblitz?

Comment: In my IDE I use the version 13.1.1. I find it is but compared to the version in Stackblitz the same problem.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71173481/9471852) may help you to understand the reason why styles are not getting applied to the preview element. You can try to use Solution 2 and that should resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For draggable mode styles you can use ng-deep without host. and for static styles (when they are not dragged) use : host ::ng-deep

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).